# Expectation of squared error

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, expected-value

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ an observation data matrix, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ two random variable matrices

I want to calculate:
$$E[(X_{ij} - A_iB_j)^2] = ?$$, where $X_{ij}$ is the $ij^{Th}$ element of X, $A_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $A$ and $B_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of $B$

Here is my try:

\begin{align}
E[(X_{ij} - A_iB_j)^2] &= E[(X_{ij} - A_iB_j)(X_{ij} - A_iB_j)]\\
 & = E[X_{ij}^2 - 2X_{ij}A_iB_j + (A_iB_j)^2]\\ 
 & = E[X_{ij}^2] - E[2X_{ij}A_iB_j] + E[(A_iB_j)^2]\\ 
\end{align}
Does this make sense ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see no issues here. You're just doing $(u-v)^2 = u^2 - 2uv + v^2$ where $u$ and $v$ are the scalars $X_{ij}$ and $A_i B_j$.

Comment: thank you @angryavian, I appreciated your comment.

Comment: @angryavian, while searching I found another expression that confused me
$$E[(X_{ij} - A_iB_j)^2] = (X_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^{K}E[A_{ik}]E[B_{jk}])^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{K}(E[A_{ik}^2]E[B_{jk}^2] - E[A_{ik}]^2E[B_{jk}]^2)$$
Are the two formulas equivalent?. I tried to develop further my expression but could not figure out how to get this formula. Could you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question in the main post looks fine: $(u-v)^2 = u^2-2uv + v^2$ where $u$ and $v$ are the scalars $X_{ij}$ and $A_i B_j$ respectively.

---

Response to comment:

Let $Z = A_i B_j$ be a scalar random variable. Note that in your setup, $X_{ij}$ is non-random.

\begin{align}
E[(X_{ij} - Z)^2]
&= E[(X_{ij} - E[Z] + E[Z]-Z)^2]
\\
&= E\big[(X_{ij} - E[Z])^2 + 2 (X_{ij} - E[Z])(E[Z]-Z) + (E[Z]-Z)^2\big]
\\
&= \underbrace{(X_{ij} - E[Z])^2}_{\text{non-random}} + 2 \underbrace{(X_{ij}-E[Z])}_{\text{non-random}}\underbrace{(E[E[Z]-Z])}_{=E[Z] - E[Z] = 0} + E[(E[Z]-Z)^2]
\\
&= (X_{ij} - E[Z])^2 + E[(Z-E[Z])^2]
\\
&= (X_{ij} - E[Z])^2 + \text{Var}(Z).
\end{align}

Note that $Z=A_iB_j = \sum_{k=1}^K A_{ik} B_{jk}$. Using independence of the entries of $A$ and $B$, note that $E[Z] = \sum_{k=1}^K E[A_{ik}] E[B_{jk}]$
$$\text{Var}(Z) = \text{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^K A_{ik} B_{ik}\right)
= \sum_{k=1}^K \text{Var}(A_{ik} B_{ik})
= \sum_{k=1}^K (E[A_{ik}^2 B_{ik}^2] - E[A_{ik} B_{ik}]^2)
= \sum_{k=1}^K \left(E[A_{ik}^2] E[B_{ik}^2] - E[A_{ik}]^2 E[B_{ik}]^2\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much @angryavian, in the third and fourth ligne do you mean $E[(E(Z)-Z)^2]$, I think a symbol $E$ is missing.

For the last step, why we should introduce the sum and work with elements instead of vectors (columns / rows) ?

Comment: @MathLearner Thanks, I've corrected my typo. For your second question, I don't know; I was only proving the equality that you mentioned in your comment. You should check the context of where you found this equation to understand the motivation for looking at the individual elements.

Comment: So, when working with vectors can I write $E[A_iB_j] = E[A_i]E[B_j]$ while assuming independence.

Comment: @MathLearner Sure, as long as you understand that $E[A_i]$ is a row vector, etc.

Comment: in that case, we can instead write 
$$E[(X_{ij} - A_iB_j)^2] = (X_{ij} - E[A_i]E[B_j])^2 + E[A_{i}B{j} - E[A_i]E[B_j]]^2$$

Comment: which we can simplify further to have : $$E[(X_{ij} - A_iB_j)^2] = (X_{ij} - E[A_i]E[B_j])^2 + E[(A_iB_j)^2] - E[A_iB_j]^2$$